# Class method not returning anything

Tags: c++, return

So I have my a method for me to return a string of word

This is the method I use to generate random characters.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ )
{
    int number = rand() % 26 + 97;

    alphabets[i] = char(number);
}
```

But when I want to get the word it doesn't print anything

```
inline string Game::returnAlphabets()
{
        return alphabets;
}
```

This code works before but when I transfer to new file it doesn't work.

Comment: `MAX` and `alphabets` are... ??

Comment: Did you debug it make sure you code get invoked?

Comment: MAX is 5 which I set it globaly and alphabets are the arrays of characters. which is `char alphabets[MAX]`

Comment: `std::generate` can replace your loop. I suggest using the `<random>` header instead of `rand` as well.

Comment: @JakeLin Got no errors when running the program, just the method doesn't print anything it should be.

Comment: Add the class declaration, showing member `alphabets`.

Comment: Did it invoke the for loop to initialise alphabets array?

Comment: @JakeLin Yes. I does random the alphabets and I can get it to print but couldn't get it to return

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)! For example, I can imagine that the random characters are set up in some function but not necessarily before `returnAlphabets()` is called.

Comment: NULL terminate alphabets

Answer (score 0):

string != char[]

You need to either convert alphabet to a string, or change the return type to char*.

Comment: I know string != char[] but for me it works perfectly before. Just that now it doesn't work. Just wondering.

Comment: I'm surprised that the compiler didn't complain about this.  Anyone know why?

Comment: @seanmcl perhaps because of the presence of `std::string::string(const char* s);`? This means that the compiler will construct a `string` using that constructor and return that, assuming `alphabets` is a `char[]` or a `char *`.

Comment: @PohSun Just because something *works* doesn't mean it's right. Is there a terminating null character in `alphabets`?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try

```
#define MAX 6

memset(alphabets, 0, MAX);
for ( int i = 0 ; i < MAX - 1 ; i++ )
{
    int number = rand() % 26 + 97;

    alphabets[i] = char(number);
}

    inline string Game::returnAlphabets()
    {
            string str(alphabets);
            return str;
    }
```

Comment: Given that all characters of the array are filled with random values, it would be `return std::string(alphabets, alphabets + MAX);` to deal with the fact that the string isn't necessarily null terminated.

Comment: Well, that didn't change anything. Consider `return std::string(std::begin(alphabet), std::end(alphabet));`